# Calling ASPX method from jquery AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to call a method in a seperate ASPX file with jQuery via AJAX. After running through a number of tutorials with the same basic procedure, I'm still having no luck.

**Here's the markup**

```
<input class="myButton">
<div id="debug"></div>
```

**jquery**

```
$(".myButton").click(function(e){       
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('go');   //this triggers just fine.



    $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "/functions.aspx/ServerSideMethod",
                     data: "{'param1': 'foo'}",
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     dataType: "json",
                     async: true,
                     cache: false,
                     success: function (msg) {
                         $('div#debug').text(msg.d); 
                     }
        });



});
```

**and the ASP residing in my functions.aspx file** (all of it, completely unedited)

```
[WebMethod]
public static string ServerSideMethod(string param1)
{
    return "Message from server with parameter:"+param1;
}
```

Currently, it seems to be connecting to the page alright. The error I'm getting is as follows:

> Unknown web method ServerSideMethod. Parameter name: methodName
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Unknown web method
>   ServerSideMethod. Parameter name: methodName

Comment: I think you can use __doPostBack()
http://www.webpronews.com/postbacks-with-parameters-in-javascript-2007-01

Comment: This seems to be a good route...but how do I pass the parameters across? It seems from your link this should be possible, but I can't seem to get at them.

Comment: __doPostBack will post back the entire page. I presume @sdowswell wants to not refresh the entire page.

Answer (score 1):

Your url is likely not correct. If the page you are calling from is in the following place:

`/a/b/yourpage.aspx`

Your call is looking in the following place for your functions.aspx file

`/a/b/functions.aspx`

Ensure that the url path is correct.